# Set up TeXstudio to compile either a *.tex or a *.ltx file

Tags: compiling, texstudio

This question is probably not very specific for TeXstudio, since it has to do with command execution on a shell. Anyway, I want to set up TeXstudio to compile documents which either have  `*.tex` or `*.ltx` as fileending. The default compilation command is:

`pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

I tried the following command which obviously works, but it's somehow a not very clean solution.

`pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex \| pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.ltx`

How can I get a compilation command that does not try to compile the non-existing file (for example `foo.tex`), but compiles the existing `foo.ltx` file?

EDIT: My system is Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon with the default bash shell.

Comment: As far as I know that is dependent on the shell that TeXstudio is evoking on your system - which not only makes it OS-dependent, but also (at least among UNIX systems) dependent on which shell you've set as your default (bash, sh, tcsh, ...).

Comment: Yeah that's true. I'll add this information to the question.

Comment: latexmk will not autodetect ltx files, though it will compile them if you pass them the file with extensions. Can someone try autolatex? That might work but I don't have python installed.

Comment: I'm not using latexmk, or at least I don't know if Texstudio uses latexmk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the extended syntax `?...` for filename formatting, i.e. in your case:

`pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "?me"`

See also the explaination on special chars below the command configurations (needs to have advanced options enabled to see all the details):

[image: Special chars]